# Playstore ratings doesn't reflect what we have on our Google play console

Tags: android, google-play

Our Google playstore ratings is different from what we have on our Google play console.
This is also different depending on the user, though we are in the same country, without a VPN. This ratting also changes again if we look the rating on the google play web app or in the android app. though we are in the same country without a VPN.

Please, could anyone help us understand this inconsistency from Google?

Comment: I suspect only Google can answer this question - although they have [announced changes semi-recently](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2021/08/making-ratings-and-reviews-better-for.html) to provide more targeted ratings depending on what device type you have in addition to geographic region/language. Could be that the web view doesn't use the device type while the app does.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about internal Google rating workings.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic